# UINavigationBar exception when turning on autolayout

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout

I have an app that is built for iOS 5.0.

Now re-building for iOS 7. Builds fine. Plenty of the usual iOS7 GUI issues to fix, such as a MKMapView only responding to touches on left hand half of the screen after a rotation to Landscape.

So switched on autolayout.
Now it builds (with lots of deprecation warnings that I have to go through), but crashes at startup on

> due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews.
>   UINavigationBar's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call
>   super.'

Any suggestions welcome while I start on the warnings...

Comment: Are you using a custom navigation bar class?

Comment: Implemented with                                          UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:placesViewController];
    [navController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
In AppDelegate.m application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by removing the UINavigationBar from my XIB. Luckily tehre was another way to do the GUI features I needed.

I also had a problem with an MKMapView that worked fine in portrait, but in landscape, the right hand 1/3rd would not respond to touches.

The solution to this was to delete the old XIB file, and create a new one from scratch (only 10 minutes of work).

So if you are having issues when moving an iOS 5.0 project up to iOS 7.x then consider re-creating the XIB files from scratch.